# Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more > than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-by, left-join

I am working in a inventory system where need to appear all the products in the warehouse and the existences of each product is shown be the result of the SUM of each product existence(existencia) (in **table PRODUCTOS**, I use GROUP BY in cod which is the barcode number of every product) MINUS the result of the SUM of each product sell(cantidad) (in **table VENTAS**)

PART OF THE CODE OF THE SUBTRACT:

```
$existe = $row['existe'];
$vendidos = $row['cantidad'];
$tExiste = $existe - $vendidos;
```

The issue is when in **table VENTAS** shown more than one product with the same code in each entry.... when it appears just one product code or name, the list table show me the result I need.

I saw the issue when in the **table VENTAS** I add another sell with some product that is already in that table

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
>   than 1 row (63): PDO->query('SELECT F.foto, ...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /xxxxx/productos.php on line 63

Two captures from my two tables with the issue:

- First PRODUCTOS TABLE:
  [image]
- VENTAS TABLE:
  [image]

Here the code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT F.foto, P.id_p, P.cod, P.nombreProd, P.cat, P.subcat, 
    SUM(P.existencia) AS existe, P.vineta, P.dnm, P.compra, P.venta, P.f_vencimiento,
    P.alert_cantidad, P.descuento1, P.descuento2, SUM(V.cantidad) AS cantidad, 
    (SELECT foto FROM FOTOSP WHERE codF = cod)
    AS foto, (SELECT cantidad FROM VENTAS WHERE codV = cod)
    AS CANTIDAD FROM PRODUCTOS P
    LEFT JOIN FOTOSP F ON  P.cod = F.codF 
    LEFT JOIN VENTAS V ON  P.cod = V.codV 
GROUP BY cod ORDER BY id_p DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);     // HERE IS THE LINE 63
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $existe = $row['existe'];
    $vendidos = $row['cantidad'];
    $tExiste = $existe - $vendidos;
```

Here part of the table body:

```
<td><?php echo $row['cod']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nombreProd']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $tExiste; ?></td>     // HERE NEED TO SHOW THE RESULT OF THE SUBTRACT
<td><?php echo $row['compra']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['venta']; ?></td>
```

---

EDIT

When I add GROUP BY codV in the sub select the error is gone

```
(SELECT cantidad FROM VENTAS WHERE codV = cod GROUP BY codV) AS CANTIDAD
```

BUT the issue is with the product where is more than once....instead of make the subtract (35 - 18 = 17) shown 52 ... ???

Apparently it is multiplying 35 by 2 and them make the subtract.

```
 35 * 2 = 70 //  the existence in table PRODUCTOS IS 35 NOT 70 (35*2), why is multiplying itself?
-18 = 52 // 18 is the result of SUM(13+5) because are two times in the table
```

And the other product in table VENTAS is SUM the quantity(cantidad) too

```
24 -  // the existence in table PRODUCTOS
10+10 = 4  // the quantity sold is 10 and in the table is only one time...not 20(10+10)
```

Comment: the error is exactly correct. you're using a subselect in your query, in a context where it can only return ONE row with ONE value. In your case, it's returning one value, but multiple rows of that value.

Comment: Try to set `LIMIT 1` on your subquery

Comment: @BeingSunny the thing is that I need to shown the existence of all products...not just one

Comment: Try `SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM VENTAS WHERE codV = cod` (probably slow).

Comment: @MarcB yes it is, but How can I fix the issue and the the query shown me all the result with the real existence(with the subtract of those two row `SUM(existencia) - SUM(cantidad)`)

Comment: @lmz With that just show me one product with the SUM of all product

Comment: @user3236149 I am not sure why you need subselects at all then. just use `SUM(V.cantidad) AS cantidad` and `F.foto AS foto`. That will sum up both the cantidad and the existencia.

Comment: @lmz  I know that works without the sub select, but when I do it like you said(without the subselect) the existence of some products change and not shown the real... and with the sub select and with the GROUP BY in the sub select of table VENTAS the issue is only in the product where are more than one in the table VENTAS